# wx.webkit -- how to get current URL...?

Tags: browser, webkit, wxpython

I am trying to build a custom browser using wx.webkit. The following code works cleanly.

I want to get the current URL of the page that is being currently displayed. Using the GetPageURL() method does not seem to help. This always displays the starting URL (http://www.google.com in this case). It does not seem to get updated.

How can i get the updated URL when i navigate from one page to another...?

```
import wx
import wx.webkit

class wxBrowser(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(800, 625))

    self.browser = wx.webkit.WebKitCtrl(self,-1) 
    self.browser.LoadURL('http://www.google.com')
    self.browser.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.PrintURL)
    self.Centre()
    self.Show(True)

  def PrintURL(self, event):
    # show current URL on Cmd P
    if event.CmdDown() and event.GetKeyCode() == 80:
        print self.browser.GetPageURL()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = wx.App()
  wxBrowser(None, -1, 'My Browser')
  app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I found a method myself. One can use the RunScript() method of wx.webkit.WebKiCtrl and a simple javascript to get the URL.   self.browser.RunScript("document.URL") returns the current URL. I would still like to know if there is any direct method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wx.html2.WebView.New widget instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a get_uri() method. You have to use it like this

```
browser = webkit.WebView()
browser.open("http://example.com")
print browser.get_main_frame().get_uri()
```